# How to indent only a part of a sentence?

Tags: latex, tex

I'd like to indent only a part of a sentence in LaTex, but it just doesn't work out for me.
I tried to use different functions like \parindent or \hangindent, but unfortunately I did not get it.

The desired result is shown in the picture.

[image: LaTex Problem Screenshot]

Comment: Have a look at the `description` environment. Or place to minipages side-by-side.

Comment: thank you so mouch! minipages did the job :)